# Simplify the expression: $\sim ((p\rightarrow (\sim q \vee r))\wedge (\sim p \wedge \sim q \wedge \sim r ))$

Tags: boolean-algebra

Simplify the expression:

$\sim ((p\rightarrow (\sim q \vee r))\wedge (\sim p \wedge \sim q \wedge \sim r ))$

**Correct answer:**  $p\vee q\vee r$

I don't know how to start on this problem. Are there some useful laws to use here or is there something else I should do when simplifying?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just simplify the expression.  Knowing the equivalence $A\to B\equiv \lnot A\lor B$ and de Morgan's laws is a start.

\begin{align*}
&\lnot ((p\rightarrow (\lnot q \lor r))\land (\lnot p \land \lnot q \land \lnot r ))\\
&= \lnot(p\rightarrow (\lnot q \lor r))\lor \lnot(\lnot p \land \lnot q \land \lnot r ) && (\text{de Morgan})\\
&= \lnot(\lnot p\lor (\lnot q \lor r))\lor (\lnot\lnot p \lor \lnot\lnot q \lor \lnot\lnot r ) &&(\text{definition, de Morgan})\\
&= (\lnot\lnot p\land\lnot(\lnot q \lor r))\lor (\lnot\lnot p \lor \lnot\lnot q \lor \lnot\lnot r ) &&(\text{de Morgan})\\
&= ((\lnot\lnot p\land\lnot(\lnot q \lor r))\lor \lnot\lnot p) \lor (\lnot\lnot q \lor \lnot\lnot r )\\
&= (\lnot\lnot p) \lor (\lnot\lnot q \lor \lnot\lnot r ) && (\text{absorption})\\
&=p\lor q\lor r && (\text{double negation})
\end{align*}